# python taking input in a row and doing operation simulatneously

Tags: python

How I can take input in a row and doing operation with that in Python such 2,3,4,5 as a input and simultaneously doing operation with input.
Not taking input row first and do operation.
I want to do operation while taking input in a row like C.
my output will be 2 5 9 14.

but i will make sum while taking input.

**

sum=0
li1=[]
while taking input:
input =taking input in a row
sum+=input
li1[position]=sum
sum+=input

**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are on Windows or on Linux, but for Windows a module that should do the job you are looking for is `msvcrt`, ([the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html)) especially the `getch` function will hopefully solve your problem.

An example could be:

```
import msvcrt

sum = 0
while True:
    key = msvcrt.getwch()
    try:
        sum += int(key)
    except:
        exit(1)
```

You would still have to implement a `break` condition here, I can sadly not test it because I am not on Windows